# Deactivate FlatButton default Sound and animation

Tags: flutter, dart

Developping an app with Flutter and I can't deactivate the default sound (and animation) of the FlatButton.

I can't find any doc about that sound in the official doc
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlatButton-class.html.

I tried a MaterialButton and a RawMaterialButton but it has the same sound and animation...

Any help appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by 'sound'? That's weird behavior. Add video/image/gif to illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am on the same thing and found as a solution using the InkWell Widget instead like this:

```
child: InkWell(
                  enableFeedback: false, //if true, sound and vibration are enable
                  child: Text('Testing'),
                  onTap: () {
                    //your code
                  },
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `MatierialButton` has no default animation or sound. Something else is causing it. Try it out on a fresh emulator to see.